# Find minimum of a column with condition on another, for every observation

Tags: r

I have a DataFrame consisting of almost 200,000 Observations.
The Important columns are similar to (NOTE: The Min Value is not filled by default)

```
Key        Value      Min Value
1xA         1           1
2xA         2           2
3xB         3           2 
1xB         1           1
1xA         5           1 
2xB         2           2
3xB         2           2
2xA         4           2
```

How can achieve this to fill the Min Value column in R?
I tried looping in the dataframe and finding minimum of a subset created for key while checking that particular observation, and it worked fine.
But it takes too much time to carry out the 200,000 Observation iteration.

My Thoughts: I was thinking if there was any way to filter out using which() for every observation in one go so that I can find the min. then and there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, this is not too complicated:

```
df
#    Key Value
# 1 1xA     1
# 2 2xA     2
# 3 3xB     3
# 4 1xB     1
# 5 1xA     5
# 6 2xB     2
# 7 3xB     2
# 8 2xA     4

df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Key) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Min.Value = min(Value))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Key [5]
#   Key   Value Min.Value
#   <fct> <int>     <dbl>
# 1 1xA       1         1
# 2 2xA       2         2
# 3 3xB       3         2
# 4 1xB       1         1
# 5 1xA       5         1
# 6 2xB       2         2
# 7 3xB       2         2
# 8 2xA       4         2
```

Comment: This works like charm.

Comment: Is it possible to find any additional column(s) corresponding to the minimum value, and fill it like a a reference in all the grouped observation?

Answer (score 0):

With basic functions only:

```
merge(df, aggregate(list(Min.Value=df$Value), by=list(key=df$Key), FUN=min), by="Key")
```

The `aggregate` function takes the `Value` column (the first parameter), groups it by the values supplied with the `by` parameter (must be a list of vectors of the same length as the fist parameter), and applies the `FUN` function to each group (here `min`). The first parameter is wrapped to a list just to rename the resulting column (if you replace it with just `df$Value`, the resulting column will be named `x`.)

The outer `merge` joins rows of the two data frames supplied that have the same value in the `Key`column (i.e. much like database *join* operation).

Comment: The basic problem with using merge is that it follows the iterative way, hence quite slow. 200,000+ data set will take me ages.