# Find Minimum of a column and corresponding row of the minimum with condition on another column

Tags: r

```
Key        Value Value2      Min Value Min Value2
1xA         1      2            1         2
2xA         2      3            2         3
3xB         3      1            2         2
1xB         1      1            1         1
1xA         5      5            1         2
2xB         2      6            2         6
3xB         2      2            2         2
2xA         4      1            2         3
```

In correspondence to the question I raised in this: [Find minimum of a column with condition on another, for every observation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644029/find-minimum-of-a-column-with-condition-on-another-for-every-observation-in-r)

The Column `Min. Value` is the minimum `Value` corresponding to every `Key` How can I also fill the `Min Value2` which will be the `Value2`corresponding to the `Min. Value`obtained for every Key?

Comment: What did you try based on the answer to your previous question?

Comment: `df <-df %>% group_by(Key) %>% mutate("Min Value" = min(Value))`

This solved my Problem totally.

Answer (score 1):

You can first calculate `min` for the group and look for row number of row containing `min` value which can be used to get `Value2`.

A solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Key) %>%
  mutate(MinValue = min(Value)) %>%
  mutate(MinValue2 = Value2[which(Value==MinValue)[1]]) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   Key Value Value2 MinValue MinValue2
# 1 1xA     1      2        1         2
# 2 2xA     2      3        2         3
# 3 3xB     3      1        2         2
# 4 1xB     1      1        1         1
# 5 1xA     5      5        1         2
# 6 2xB     2      6        2         6
# 7 3xB     2      2        2         2
# 8 2xA     4      1        2         3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Key        Value Value2      
1xA         1      2         
2xA         2      3         
3xB         3      1         
1xB         1      1         
1xA         5      5         
2xB         2      6         
3xB         2      2         
2xA         4      1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```